# i make a program in z80 PIO using conditional , but the result is different

Tags: assembly, microprocessors, z80

Program to make output port B = FFH, if and only if input port A = 01H
(another input then output is 00)

Here my code:

```
       LD     A, 4FH
       OUT    (82H), A
       LD     A, 0FH
       OUT    (83H), A
LOOP:   IN     A,(80H)
        CP     01H
        JR     NZ,S1
        LD     A,00H
S1:     LD     A,FFH
        OUT    (81H),A
        JP     LOOP
```

the problem is when i give input another than 01, the output still FF

Comment: What does the initial output of `4F` -> `82`and `0F`-> `83` do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit rusty since I haven't used Z80 assembler in 35 years, but it seems to me like you'll `LD A,FFH` before output every loop.

Consider adding a label (`S2`) and jumping to that after having loaded `A` with `00H` - and haven't you swapped the `JR NZ` logic? `JR NZ` jumps if `CP 01H` doesn't set `Z`.

```
        LD     A, 4FH
        OUT    (82H), A
        LD     A, 0FH
        OUT    (83H), A

LOOP:   IN     A,(80H)
        CP     01H
        JR     NZ,S1      ; jump to S1 if 01 was not read
        LD     A,FFH      ; we got 01, load FF
        JR     S2         ; ... and jump to S2

S1:     LD     A,00H      ; will only be reached if 01 was not read

S2:     OUT    (81H),A
        JP     LOOP       ; could probably be  JR LOOP
```